# Library for parsing strings containing units

Tags: c++, units-of-measurement

I'm looking for a C++ library which can parse user-provided strings such as the following:

```
25 meters/day
3.4 light-years/s
10 cm^3 yr^-1
```

And return these as objects which can be added, multiplied, et cetera.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: It\s old and not updated for long, but how about [libunits](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libunits/)? I'm sure there are more if you search.

Comment: T‎ake look at [boost::units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Comment: @n.m., to my understanding this a compile-time library. Since I intend to parse and manipulate user input, I doubt whether such a library would work for me.

Comment: If someone gives you "25 meters/day + 3.4 light-years/s" do you need to do the conversions?

Comment: @brianbeuning, not necessarily in the addition, but I need some way to cast the magnitude of one object to the units of another.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the *dimension* of the quantity in advance (and I imagine that you do if you are solving a real physical problem) you can still use Boost.Units since a conversion factor is always bound to exists(be defined). Like here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html#boost_units.Examples.RuntimeUnits

If the problem is really the parsing of the unit names/operations then Boost.Spirit or C++ regex can help in addition.